# Change iptables log format

Tags: iptables, log

Is it possible to change the log format of iptables ?

I want to add the ssh_client in the log.

I have already made an iptables rule for outgoing ssh

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j LOG --log-prefix "outbound ssh ${SSH_CLIENT%% *} : " --log-ip-options "${SSH_CLIENT%% *}" --syn
```

but I want the variable ${SSH_CLIENT%% *} to be dynamic and not static.

I want the log this because i want to know if a user with a ssh session open another ssh session ( Bouncing ssh )

Comment: What is `${SSH_CLIENT%% *}` supposed to expand to?

Comment: For example we have two server (A) and (B) and computer (C).

(C) can to connect to (A) by ssh but can't to (B).

and (A) can connect to (B). so (C) can do a multi-hop ssh to (B). (C) -> (A) -> (B). So if (C) do i multi-hop to (B) ${SSH_CLIENT%% *}=ip_addresse(C) in server A

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially bullet point lists and file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

For outgoing connections, e.g.:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j LOG --log-prefix "Outgoing SSH connection "
```

Check the log entries:

```
less /var/log/kern.log
```

If you reboot, your iptables configuration disappears. Save your configuration with:

```
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01firewall
```

Paste this script:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/logger ]; then
        LOGGER="/usr/bin/logger -s -p daemon.info -t FirewallHandler"
else
        LOGGER=echo
fi

case "$2" in
        up)
                if [ ! -r /etc/iptables.rules ]; then
                        ${LOGGER} "No iptables rules exist to restore."
                        return
                fi
                if [ ! -x /sbin/iptables-restore ]; then
                        ${LOGGER} "No program exists to restore iptables rules."
                        return
                fi
                ${LOGGER} "Restoring iptables rules"
                /sbin/iptables-restore -c < /etc/iptables.rules
                ;;
        down)
                if [ ! -x /sbin/iptables-save ]; then
                        ${LOGGER} "No program exists to save iptables rules."
                        return
                fi
                ${LOGGER} "Saving iptables rules."
                /sbin/iptables-save -c > /etc/iptables.rules
                ;;
        *)
                ;;
esac
```

and make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01firewall
```

More infos about [Logging](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Logging) and [Configuration on Startup for NetworkManager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Configuration_on_Startup_for_NetworkManager).